# getScreenshotAs is giving null exception on webDriver

Tags: java, spring, selenium, testng, allure

I am using spring framework with selenium and testNG, then I decided to integrate with allure reports, the reports are working fine.

My issue is with attaching screenshots on failure.
The *@Autowired driver* is returning null when *getScreenshotAs* is called.

I'll post some code, if more is needed let me know.

```
@Component
public class ScreenshotUtil {
    
    @Autowired
    private WebDriver driver;
    
    @Attachment(value = "Screenshot", type = "image/png")
    public byte[] saveScreenshotOnFailure() {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES); //this is where im getting error
    }
}
```

Then I have the listener class..

```
public class AllureListener implements ITestListener {

    @Autowired
    private ScreenshotUtil screenshotUtil;
    
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        screenshotUtil.saveScreenshotOnFailure();
    }
}
```

I have my test classes with @Test all working fine.. I'll add the WebDriverConfig component aswell (dont know if that will be useful).

```
@Configuration
public class WebDriverConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Scope("browserscope") //This is for parallel run
    public WebDriver driver() {
        if(System.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox") {
            .. return firefox driver //let me know if this code might be necessary
        } else {
            .. return chrome driver //let me know if this code might be necessary
        }
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebDriverWait webDriverWait(WebDriver driver) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my own question, because after a lot of help and some research I was able to solve this issue.

What happens is, spring context is different from testNG context.
When we implement ITestListener class, the TestNG context does not have access to spring context. This class is necessary for taking screenshots on test failure.

So the solution is (I took it from here: https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-spring-beans-into-classes-not-managed-by-spring)

First create this service to retrieve the beans from spring:

```
@Service
public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

Then on my AllureListener class I'll retrieve the ScreenshotUtil bean like this:

```
public class AllureListener implements ITestListener {
    
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        ScreenshotUtil screenshotUtil = BeanUtil.getBean(ScreenshotUtil.class);
        screenshotUtil.saveScreenshotOnFailure();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future using spring framework, spring and allure report.

Answer (score 0):

See if the @Component annotation will solve your issue, since you're using @Autowired on a property.

Decorate the driver() method in WebDriverConfig with @Component("driver"); and see if it works.
More details here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt work, i've tried that before :(

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could put the entire stack trace.
It appears that the configuration class is not able to provide the driver bean.
You can try the following two things.

1. Try removing the @Scope (which would make the bean singleton that shouldn't be an issue here, you can use "prototype" scope )
2. Debug the code place debug point inside the Bean and see if the bean is getting returned.

Comment: with some help i was able to understand what the issue is.. Spring starts its own context, same thing happens to TestNG. When the test fails and the method onTestFailure is called, testNG is using its own context and the driver (which was defined in the spring context) is null.